# jupyter notebook blank screen in browser

Tags: windows, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, visual-studio-2019

When I run Jupyter notebook and go to the browser at the specified address, a blank page is loaded.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQRft.jpg)

logs that fly out in cmd:

```
[I 19:11:21.500 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 19:11:21.500 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 19:11:21.516 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Nikita Permikov\source\repos\Jupyter notebook
[I 19:11:21.516 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 19:11:21.516 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/
[I 19:11:21.516 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 19:11:38.690 NotebookApp] 302 GET /tree? (::1) 2.00ms
```

ОС: Windows 10 home
Python: "python" is registered in the path
Anaconda installed with Visual Studio 2019

Already reinstalled jupyter

Comment: Please translate your question to English. Alternatively, there is a Russian language Stack Overflow site at https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252159/jupyter-notebook-opens-an-empty-browser

Answer (score 0):

installed jupyter and try to uninstall notebook version 5.7.8 and install notebook 5.7.4 instead. while in that jupyter notebook page try to press CTRL + Shift + R and it will clear all the cache in the browser of that file. it works for me rather than install and uninstalling the jupyter.